# Get data based on the user's query and pass it to databinding [uses MVVM]

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, android-livedata

I am having a DB populated with weather data, in both imperial and metric units. Now, I have made two different classes which act as a model to get data from the DB. `CurrentWeatherMetric` has only metric columns, and `CurrentWeatherImperial` has only imperial fields.

Since I am using MVVM architecture pattern, the `ViewModel` provides me this data, by calling a function in ViewModel `getData(Unit.METRIC)` where `Unit` is an `enum class` I've made to distinguish the data.

The problem arises here.
My viewModel looks like:

```
class WeatherViewModel(
    private val weatherRepository: WeatherRepositoryImpl
) : ViewModel() {

    lateinit var currentWeather: LiveData<CurrentWeather>
    lateinit var forecastWeather: LiveData<List<ForecastWeather>>

    fun getValuesOfUnit(unit: Unit) {
        currentWeather = when (unit) {
            Unit.IMPERIAL->weatherRepository.getCurrentWeatherImperial()
            Unit.METRIC->weatherRepository.getCurrentWeatherMetric()
        }
        getWeather()
    }

    private fun getWeather() {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                weatherRepository.getWeather()
            } catch (e: IOException) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, `lateinit var currentWeather: LiveData<CurrentWeather>`, 
I had to make another class which store the data of the query with units. I made this so that I could easily implement databinding with it. But I feel this is a really wrong way to do things and hence I have asked this question. How can I get rid of that `lateinit` variable and implement databinding to adapt to any of the data.

In my current data binding layout, I have data field as:

```xml
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.mythio.weather.ui.WeatherViewModel" />
</data>
```

And I bind to views by:

```xml
   app:someattribute="@{viewModel.currentWeather.temperature}"
```

If the question title makes a little sense about what I am asking,  or seems misleading, please feel free to edit this to make it a better question.

Comment: In spite of taking **lateinit** you can also initialize it with `MutableLiveData` in same line with declaration something like `val data: LiveData<> = MutableLiveData()`. Although UI binding seems okay to me.

Comment: So the way I have implemented the rest of the code is okay?

Comment: Yes, following MVVM and getting data from Repository is best practice in my opinion. Recommended way is that bind your ViewModel to UI and get data from Repository which always would be single source of truth for your data.

Comment: Ok thanks! If you would write an answer, I will mark it as correct

Comment: But I didn't help you much though to receive such reputation.

Comment: It still helped me a lot as someone new to kotlin and mvvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using **MVVM architecture pattern**, *Google's recommended* way is to make **`ViewModel`** that handles connection between your *data and view*, so it contains UI logic as well as some portion of business logic bound to your UI.

Moreover, implementation of `ViewModel` in recommended way helps you handle **UI lifecycle** (Activity/Fragments) in better and hassle-free way.

When using **data-binding with MVVM**, it's good practice to bind `ViewModel` directly to xml so that, when data changes you can directly reflect it to UI using **`LiveData`** without wiring it manually.

Hence, `LiveData` can be used as Data-Value holder as it's also *Lifecycle-aware component*.

---

On the other hand, **Repositories** are good way to manage *business logic* and providing *"single source of truth"* for data driving through app. So, all data sources like **local-db, API calls, shared-preferences** etc. should be accessed via repository.

So, yes!! Things you're doing are good & you're on the right track while following **MVVM Architecture Pattern**.

> Note: *You can **refer [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide)** for more info and some improvements in your code.*